# Export mySQL table records to individual files

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to generate individual text files from an SQL query result.   Given a table like:

| fileName | fileContents |
| --- | --- |
| name1.txt | "text1" |
| name2.txt | "text2" |
| ... | ... |
| name100.txt | "text100" |

is there a simple way to create a text file for each row containing `fileContents` and named `fileName?`   Thanks in advance!

Comment: Iterational stored procedure may do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need in something like this (not tested, debugging needed):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE save_to_files ()
BEGIN
DECLARE not_done INT DEFAULT TRUE;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT fileName, fileContents FROM tablename;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET not_done = FALSE;
OPEN cur;
FETCH cur INTO @fn, @fc;
WHILE not_done 
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ? INTO DUMPFILE "', @fn, '";');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @fc;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
    FETCH cur INTO @fn, @fc;
END WHILE;
CLOSE cur;
END
```

Comment: This took me a while to debug but now works like a charm. Needed to add a `DO` after the WHILE, and declare the `fn` and `fc` as local variables for the FETCH before using them as user-defined variables in the EXECUTE.  Thank you @Akina!!